# For all sequences $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $(y_n)$ converges to $0$ if and only if $(||y_n||)$ converges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

For all sequences $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $(y_n)$ converges to $0$ if and only if $(||y_n||)$ converges to $0$.

Hints on how to go about proving this?  Is there a way to argue that if $|r| < 1$ then $x_n = r^n$ converges to $0$.

For the forward implication if $(y_n)$ converges to $0$ then don't we have $(||y_n||)$ = $(||0||)$ or doesn't this work since sequences are not continuous?

Comment: small hint: norms have the property that $\|x\| = 0$ iff $x = 0$.

Comment: Presumably the "$y_n$ converges to 0" statement means that each component of $y_n$ coverges to 0? Otherwise you're proving a definition.

Comment: @AlexR. Presumably, $\mathbb R^n$ is a metric space, and in a metric space, by definition, $y_n$ converges to $y$ if $d(y_n, y)$ is small enough for large values of $n$...

Comment: Sorry but this is the very definition of convergence to $0$ for the distance induced by $\|\ \|$ (and neither the convergence of components nor a condition for the norm being $0$ are involved...).

Comment: @5xum shouldn't be a metric space but a norm space.

Comment: @IdleMathGuy Every normed space is a metric space...

Comment: @5xum my apologies, I've studied norms in my classes but we haven't gone over metric spaces yet.  Hence, there is a knowledge gap.

Comment: @IdleMathGuy It's no problem. In my answer below, there is no mention of a metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write out the definitions. The definition of convergence in $\mathbb R^n$ is:

> $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $x$ if and only if, for every $\epsilon 
>   > 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n>N$, $\|x_n-x\|<\epsilon$

and the definition of convergence in $\mathbb R$ is

> $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $a$ if and only if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that if $n>N$, then $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$

---

Now, apply it to your case:

> $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $0$ if and only if, for every $\epsilon 
>   > 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n>N$, $\|y_n-0\|<\epsilon$

and

> $\{\|y_n\|\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $0$ if and only if, for every $\epsilon 
>   > 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|\|y_n\|-0|<\epsilon$

Now, simplify the expressions in the two cases, and you'll see how similar they become.